# Displaying the type of post (Custom) in a single.php

Tags: custom-post-types

How can I display the type of custom post type in a template?

So: `<h3> [CUSTOM POST TYPE] </h3>`?

Answer (score 2):

Already figured it out:

```
<?php $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type($post->ID) );?>
<h3><?php echo $post_type->label ?></h3>
```

Comment: `$post->post_type` no need to use `get_post_type()` here as you already have the post object :)